# Swift - How to understand Shorthand Argument Names

Tags: swift

According to the documentation "Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s arguments by the names $0, $1, $2, and so on."

```
reversed​ = ​sorted​(​names​, { ​s1​, ​s2​ ​in​ ​s1​ > ​s2​ } )
```

can be modified to :

```
​reversed​ = ​sorted​(​names​, { ​$0​ > ​$1​ } )
```

in another other code snippet,

```
var viewModel: ArticleViewViewModel {
    didSet {
    viewModel.title.bindAndFire {
        [unowned self] in
        self.titleLabel.text = $0
  }
....
```

1,Why does `$0` not represent `[unowned self]` ?

2,Why does '$0' equal to viewModel.title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [unowned self] is a closure capture list, it's not an argument.

```
{ 
[unowned self]  // Capture list
(a:String, b:Int) //Arguments names
 in
   ...   //Closure body
}
```

Capture lists appear as the first item in a closure. They’re listed before any parameter clauses or identifier lists and require the in keyword to be used.

Strong Reference Cycles for Closures from [The Swift Programming Language Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

> ....
>
> This strong reference cycle occurs because closures, like classes, are
>   reference types. When you assign a closure to a property, you are
>   assigning a reference to that closure. In essence, it’s the same
>   problem as above—two strong references are keeping each other alive.
>   However, rather than two class instances, this time it’s a class
>   instance and a closure that are keeping each other alive.
>
> **Swift provides an elegant solution to this problem, known as a closure capture list**. However, before you learn how to break a
>   strong reference cycle with a closure capture list, it is useful to
>   understand how such a cycle can be caused.

Example of closure :

```
[1, 2, 3].map( { (i: Int) ->Int in return i * 2 } )
[1, 2, 3].map( { i in return i * 2 } )
[1, 2, 3].map( { i in i * 2 } )
[1, 2, 3].map( { $0 * 2 } )
[1, 2, 3].map() { $0 * 2 }
[1, 2, 3].map { $0 * 2 }
```

Based on source you've provide I believe the original came from 
http://rasic.info/bindings-generics-swift-and-mvvm/

```
class Dynamic<T> {
  typealias Listener = T -> Void
  var listener: Listener?

  func bind(listener: Listener?) {
    self.listener = listener
  }

  func bindAndFire(listener: Listener?) {
    self.listener = listener
    listener?(value)
  }

  var value: T {
    didSet {
      listener?(value)
    }
  }

  init(_ v: T) {
    value = v
  }
}
```

Comment: Still not understand what $0 stand for?For the caller if there are not argument state?

Comment: Consider following closure :

(value0:Int,value1:Int) -> Int 

It takes 2 Integer params and returns Integer

{
(value0:Int,value1:Int) 
in
   return value0+value1
}

or

{
 return $0+$1 // Where $0 = value0 , $1 = value1
}

Comment: $0 stand for first parameter passed to closure, $1 to second, $2 to third and so on.

Comment: In this code snippet from "http://rasic.info/bindings-generics-swift-and-mvvm/"                                                                                                                  viewModel.title.bindAndFire {
        [unowned self] in
        self.titleLabel.text = $0
      }              why $0 equal to viewModel.title ?   there no argument on the closure.

Comment: Is that mean the "an argument" point to the propertiy "value" of Dynamic<T>?